# Vue js 2 hide shared component

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vue-router

```
<template>
<div id="app" class="phone-viewport">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500,700,400italic">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">

  <router-view></router-view>
  <bottomBar v-bind:visibles='show' ></bottomBar>

</div>
</template>

<script>
export default {

  name: '',
  show: '',

  data () {
    return {
      visibles: [
        {name: 'Football', show: true},
        {name: 'Basketball', show: true},
        {name: 'Hockey', show: true},
        {name: 'VolleyBall', show: false},
        {name: 'Baseball', show: false},

      ]
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

I'm looking to hide the bottomBar just on VolleyBall and Beisbol .
But I always have this error "Property or method "show" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render. Make sure to declare reactive data properties in the data option.
"

```
<script>
export default {

  name: 'app',

  data () {
    return {}
  },
  computed: {
    hideBottom: function () {
      if (this.$router.path === '/baseball' || this.$router.path === '/volleyball') return false
      else { return true }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: did it help you or upvote is from someone else?

Answer (score 1):

1. Baseball
2. You are calling method show which does not exist, that's why you are getting that error.
3. As I understand your question, you want to hide that component on particular routes?
4. If so, You need to create `computed` variable which will determine if it should be shown or not. e.g.:

```
computed: {
   toShowOrNotToShow: function () {
      if(this.$router.path === '/baseball' || this.$router.path === '/volleyball') return false;
      else
          return true;
    }
  }
```

5. Just use it: `<bottomBar v-if='toShowOrNotToShow' ></bottomBar>`

Comment: I try your code but it still showing the bottomBar, should I declare some methods within the scripts tags?

Comment: Looks like you don't know how computed work.
You need to put my code into your script tag. Look at docs.https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html

Comment: Yes, i've added it inside the <script> tag but it still doesn't seem to be working. I've updated my question with the script code.

Comment: can you please add: mounted:mounted: function () {
console.log(this.$router)
        }

It may be that you don't inject router

Comment: I applied  "mounted:mounted: function () { console.log(this.$router) }" after computed properties without any result. Do you have some documentation for mounted?

Comment: Everything on vuejs website

Comment: Of course I know this site. But I'm asking for a different resource, explain it in a different way. I'm using Webpack.

Comment: Hey, thanks a bunch for your answer. I am using props (in my routes). I saw it here https://router.vuejs.org/en/essentials/passing-props.html